# Sorting a struct based on a reference array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a struct definition as

```
Player = Struct.new(:name, :level)
```

And a sample array

```
levels = [ 'level-1','level-2','beta','alpha','level4','level7']
```

I want to sort the struct in a way that the members appear in the increasing order of the levels mentioned
eg

```
[#<struct Player name="Ryan", level="beta">,
 #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">,
  #<struct Player name="Tom", level="level4">,
 #<struct Player name="Edward", level="level1">,
  #<struct Player name="Drew", level="level7">]
```

becomes

```
 #[<struct Player name="Edward", level="level1">,
 #<struct Player name="Ryan", level="beta">,
 #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">,
  #<struct Player name="Tom", level="level4">,
  #<struct Player name="Drew", level="level7">]
```

How do I go about doing that in ruby.

I tried

```
arr.sort_by { |e| [ levels.index(e.level)] }

ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
from (pry):79:in `sort_by'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it. The result of the `sort_by` block should be what you want to compare against. You want to use the index in levels, not an Array which contains the index in levels.

```
arr.sort_by { |e| levels.index(e.level) }
```

And make sure you've got your level strings correct. You may wish to use constants to avoid typos.

Comment: Just want to point out that you can optimize the time complexity here by pre-indexing the levels array, e.g. turning it into a `{ <level> => <index> }` hash so you don't have to call `.index` repeatedly

Comment: To put some flesh on @maxpleaner's suggestion: for `arr = [["Tom", "level4"], ["Ryan", "beta"], ["Chris", "alpha"]].map { |a| Player.new(*a) } #=> [#<struct Player name="Tom", level="level4">, #<struct Player name="Ryan", level="beta">, #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">]`, construct `level_to_idx = levels.each_with_index.to_a.to_h #=> {"level-1"=>0, "level-2"=>1, "beta"=>2, "alpha"=>3, "level4"=>4, "level7"=>5}`,...

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have given this question in interviews before and I always say that it's going fom O(N^2) to O(N) but it just struck me to ask if that is really true? Is the time complexity of `sort_by` O(N)?

Comment: ...then `arr.sort_by { |i| level_to_idx[i.level] } #=>  [#<struct Player name="Ryan", level="beta">, #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">, #<struct Player name="Tom", level="level4">]`. This reduces the computational complexity from O(n**2) to O(nlog(n)).

Comment: @maxpleaner, what are you talking about? I said O(nlog(n)). (Confession: I said O(n) in an expunged comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that has a computational complexity close to O(n), "close" because hash lookups are not quite constant time.

We are given:

```
Player = Struct.new(:name, :level)

arr = [["Tom", "level4"], ["Ryan", "beta"], ["Chris", "alpha"],
       ["Drew", "level4"]].map { |a| Player.new(*a) }
  #=> [#<struct Player name="Tom",   level="level4">,
  #    #<struct Player name="Ryan",  level="beta">,
  #    #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">,
  #    #<struct Player name="Drew",  level="level4">]
```

Notice that Tom and Drew have the same level.

```
levels = ['level-1','level-2','beta','alpha','level4','level7']
```

Then

```
    arr.group_by(&:level).values_at(*levels).flatten.compact
  #=>[#<struct Player name="Ryan",  level="beta">,
  #   #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">,
  #   #<struct Player name="Tom",   level="level4">,
  #   #<struct Player name="Drew",  level="level4">]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
h = arr.group_by(&:level)
  #=> {"level4"=>[#<struct Player name="Tom",   level="level4">,
  #               #<struct Player name="Drew",  level="level4">],
  #    "beta"  =>[#<struct Player name="Ryan",  level="beta">],
  #    "alpha" =>[#<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">]}
```

```
a = h.values_at(*levels)
  #=> [nil,
  #    nil,
  #    [#<struct Player name="Ryan",  level="beta">],
  #    [#<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">],
  #    [#<struct Player name="Tom",   level="level4">,
  #     #<struct Player name="Drew",  level="level4">],
  #    nil]
```

```
b = a.compact
  #=>  [[#<struct Player name="Ryan",  level="beta">],
  #     [#<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">],
  #     [#<struct Player name="Tom",   level="level4">,
  #      #<struct Player name="Drew",  level="level4">]]
```

```
c = b.flatten
  #=>  [#<struct Player name="Ryan",  level="beta">,
  #     #<struct Player name="Chris", level="alpha">,
  #     #<struct Player name="Tom",   level="level4">,
  #     #<struct Player name="Drew",  level="level4">]
```